# Super fast UART transimission return error

Tags: serial, uart, serial-data, speed, chipkit

The code was based on Fahad Mirza's very helpful example here [Send structure through Serial](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72138/send-structure-thorugh-serial/72141?noredirect=1#comment157377_72141)

The **Sender**'s code now became

```
struct Gyro_data_structure
{
  char command_name[5];
  float gyro_X;
  float gyro_Y;
  float gyro_Z;
};

Gyro_data_structure Gyro_data;
int size_gyro = sizeof(struct Gyro_data_structure);    

void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  //Serial.begin(115200); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.begin(250000);    
}   

void loop() {

  Gyro_data.command_name[0] = 'H';
  Gyro_data.command_name[2] = 'l';
  Gyro_data.gyro_X++;
  Gyro_data.gyro_Y=12;    

  Serial.write('p');
  Serial.write('L');
  Serial.write(Gyro_data.command_name, sizeof(Gyro_data.command_name));


  Serial.write('m');
  Serial.write('x');

  send(&Gyro_data);
  delay(100); //---------------------the parameter played in this post
  //Serial.flush();
}

void send (const Gyro_data_structure* table)
{
  Serial.write((const char*)table, size_gyro);  // 2 bytes.
}
```

The **Receiver**'s code

```
struct Gyro_data_structure
{
  char command_name[5];
  float gyro_X;
  float gyro_Y;
  float gyro_Z;
};

Gyro_data_structure  Gyro_data_received;
int size_gyro = sizeof(struct Gyro_data_structure);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial1.begin(9600);
  //Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(250000);
}


void loop() {

  //if(Serial1.available()>0)      
  if(Serial1.available()>=size_gyro)//----------------worked very welll//------------------------
  {
      Serial.println(Serial1.available());

    //Serial1.findUntil('p','L');
    //Serial1.find('p');
    //Serial1.find('L');

  if ((Serial1.read() == 'p') && (Serial1.read() == 'L'))
  {
    Serial1.readBytes(Gyro_data_received.command_name, sizeof(Gyro_data_received.command_name));

    Serial.println("Received confirmation");
    Serial.println(Gyro_data_received.command_name[0]);
    Serial.println(Gyro_data_received.command_name[2]);


    if ((Serial1.read() == 'm') && (Serial1.read() == 'x')) {

      Serial.println("Gyro data received");
      receive2(&Gyro_data_received);

      Serial.println(Gyro_data_received.command_name[0]);
      Serial.println(Gyro_data_received.gyro_X);
      Serial.println(Gyro_data_received.gyro_Y);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Gyro data lost");
    }

  } else {

    Serial.println("No code confirmed");
    while(Serial1.peek()!='p'){
    Serial.print(Serial1.read()); //basically clean the receiver 
    //Serial1.flush();    
    }


  }

  }
}


bool receive2(Gyro_data_structure* table)
{
  return (Serial1.readBytes((char*)table, sizeof(Gyro_data_structure)) == sizeof(Gyro_data_structure));
}
```

What it does is for sender send a 5 byte char array and a structure to receiver. If receiver received the "code", i.e. char 'p' 'L' and 'm' 'x' it read the incoming 5byte char array and structure. If the code was not confirmed, it clear the incoming bytes.

However, I encountered the following issue.

**First**, at receiver's code, one pay attention to

```
  if(Serial1.available()>0)      
  if(Serial1.available()>=size_gyro)
```

the condition for which the receiver start to process the read() sequence.

However, at **speed(9600)**, I noticed that if one use

```
if(Serial1.available()>0)
```

very often it start to read when Serial1.available()=1, and return incorrect numbers which got cleared out by

```
Serial.println("No code confirmed");
while(Serial1.peek()!='p'){
Serial.print(Serial1.read()); //basically clean the receiver 
//Serial1.flush();    
}
```

But if one use

```
  if(Serial1.available()>=size_gyro)
```

as the condition to trigger the read(), it worked out very well. On the other hand, **if one increase the serial speed to, say 115200**, this does not matter, as they both return the correct result. Could you explain to me why this was the issue, please?

**Second**, please pay attention to

```
  send(&Gyro_data);
  delay(100);
```

At speed at or above 100, with nano board and mega board, this worked out fine. But if one wants to increase the transmission speed, change delay(100) to delay(20) in sender's code, the receiver's code returns error. This issue could not be resulted by change the wiring or increase the serial speed. Especially, the receiver's at part

```
  Serial.println(Serial1.available());
```

usually return a number of 62~63 when there's an error.

Could you explain to me where did those two questions come from? Were they because the chip set on Arduino? Especially, how to achieve a communication response under 20 ms?

Comment: what two questions are you talking about?

Comment: In [my answer to your previous question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/72144), I wrote: “_Binary is, however, harder to handle: [...] you may need to define a protocol of sorts in order to get the framing right. [...] I generally recommend using ASCII unless you_ really _need the extra efficiency of a binary protocol._”. You see what I mean now?

Comment: Do you have an idea what [serial speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud) means? Think about what your program does, and how fast bits and bytes are transfered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you got some logic wrong in the receiver: you have a test for
`Serial1.available()>=size_gyro` and, when this is true, you read
`size_gyro` + 9 bytes. You should change the test in order to only start
reading when you actually have `size_gyro+9` bytes available.

Then, note that `command_name` is transmitted twice: first as part of
the 9-byte preamble (between "pL" and "mx"), then as part of the
transmitted `Gyro_data_structure`. There is no point in doing so.

> at speed(9600), I noticed that if one use `if(Serial1.available()>0)`
>   very often it start to read when Serial1.available()=1, and return
>   incorrect numbers

This is expected: you wait for 1 byte to be available in the input
buffer, then you attempt to read the 9-byte preamble. One of your calls
to `Serial1.read()` is going to find the buffer empty, and it will then
return −1.

> But if one use `if(Serial1.available()>=size_gyro)` as the condition
>   to trigger the read(), it worked out very well.

In other words, when you wait until 17 bytes are available before
reading the 9-byte preamble, you get at least the preamble right. Is
this surprising?

> if one increase the serial speed to, say 115200, this does not matter,
>   as they both return the correct result

Your code takes some time to do the reading. At a fast enough baud rate,
the serial port receives the incoming bytes faster than your code reads
them, so you never run into an empty buffer.

> if one wants to increase the transmission speed, change delay(100) to
>   delay(20) in sender's code, the receiver's code returns error

The sender is going too fast, and the receiver cannot cope with the data
rate.

> `Serial1.available()` usually returns a number of 62~63 when there's
>   an error.

This means the receive buffer is full.

Note that the receiver would be way faster if it wasn't printing so
much. Upon receiving a correct transmission, it will `Serial.println()`
a bunch of messages that should total at least 64 bytes. Transmitting
those bytes at 9600 b/s takes more than 66.5 ms.

---

**Edit**: proposed solution.

Your idea of prepending a “code” to the data structure in order to
identify a correct transmission is in the right track. This is a kind of
[format indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Format_indicators) commonly known as a “magic number” or a
“signature”. It does not ensure correct transmission with 100%
confidence, as the signature could be present by accident as part of the
data structure itself. But if the signature bytes are unlikely enough to
happen by accident, you have a pretty high confidence that wherever you
find the signature in the data stream it's the start of a new packet.
You can increase this confidence by making the signature longer, at the
cost of longer transmission times.

Now, for a matter of simplicity, I would not send the signature as two
disjoint parts. Common practice is to send it as one contiguous set of
bytes, at the very beginning of the packet. For example, I would send
your packets like so:

```cpp
// 5-byte signature, including the terminating '\0'.
const uint8_t Gyro_signature[] = "Gyro";

void Gyro_send(const Gyro_data_structure &gyro) {
    Serial1.write(Gyro_signature, sizeof Gyro_signature);
    Serial1.write((uint8_t *) &gyro, sizeof gyro);
}
```

You may want to change the signature to something less likely to happen
by accident.

On the receiver side, when you expect the signature, you read from the
port one byte at a time while counting how many correct bytes you have
so far. The algorithm goes as follows:

1. let i = 0 be the number of correct bytes received so far
2. read an incoming byte
3. if that incoming byte is correct, increment i
4. otherwise, if we just got the first signature byte, reset i = 1
5. otherwise reset i = 0
6. unless we got the full signature, go to 2

This assumes that the first signature byte doesn't appear elsewhere
within the signature. Otherwise steps 4–5 would be more complex.

Here is a receiver function that implements this algorithm, then reads
the data structure:

```cpp
void Gyro_receive(Gyro_data_structure &gyro) {

    // Read until we get a complete signature.
    int discarded = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof Gyro_signature; ) {
        if (Serial1.available()) {
            char c = Serial1.read();
            if (c == Gyro_signature[i]) {  // correct byte
                i++;
            } else if (c == Gyro_signature[0]) {  // first byte
                discarded += i;
                i = 1;
            } else {
                discarded += i+1;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (discarded) {
        Serial.print("Discarded ");
        Serial.print(discarded);
        Serial.println(" bytes.");
    }

    // Wait for the data.
    while ((size_t) Serial1.available() < sizeof gyro)
        /* wait */;

    // Read it.
    Serial1.readBytes((char *) &gyro, sizeof gyro);
}
```

Note that this function is blocking. If you need a non-blocking version,
you should be able to easily convert the signature-checking part into a
finite state machine where `i` is the state variable.